# repositioning images on an HTML5 canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm writing the beginning of code for an HTML5 and java game, and I am stuck right now because I want to move my character (the image astronaut1.png) across the screen as my game piece. I have not coded anything for animation yet, I am just concerned that right now my astronaut image is being generated only because it appears in the HTML code because every time I change the position in line 35 of my code, the astronaut remains in the same corner of the screen. I am changing the position of the image via ctx.drawimage (img, x, y) to be exact.

Here is my HTML:

And here is my Java:

```
function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
}
//defines area, goes on to draw the canvas
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1270;
        this.canvas.height = 700;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("character");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200);
}
```

Comment: html is: !DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script-1.js"></script>
</head>
 <body onload="startGame()">
 <img id="character" width="75" height="100" src="astronaut1.png">
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Do you ever set the canvas' `id` to `myCanvas`? Don't you have some errors in your developer's console?

Comment: what is my developer's console? I went and reset the id in both the original drawing of the canvas myGameArea and in the window.onload function so that it is canvas: document.CreateElement("canvas") and in the window.onload function so that var c= document.getElementByID ("canvas") However the image still will not reposition

Comment: do you mean the google developer console? its not being much help right now with code. I'm getting error messages on things like c.getContext (since I'm still learning I took this from W3 schools and it runs in the same browser on that page)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. First clean up your code until all these errors have been fixed. Then come back here if your problem persists. (I'm sure it will be fixed too at this time ;-) ). Good luck with your project and happy-coding.